# Python Memory 'Blank' Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, ubuntu-16.04

Firstly I'm running on Ubuntu and using Anaconda for my kernels in Jupyter Notebook.

I keep getting the following error. I believe it suggests I'm running out of memory but I'm not sure how to solve this. Someone suggested uninstalling Python3 32 and installing Python3 64 but this broke my Ubuntu installation immediately after uninstalling python (whoops) and I had to reinstall.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-8b765500013f> in <module>()
----> 1 _, S, _ = np.linalg.svd(features)
      2 print("Condition number from the SVD: {0:.1f}".format(np.max(S)/np.min(S)))
      3 print("Condition number from cond:    {0:.1f}".format(np.linalg.cond(features)))

/home/n/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py in svd(a, full_matrices, compute_uv)
   1387 
   1388         signature = 'D->DdD' if isComplexType(t) else 'd->ddd'
-> 1389         u, s, vt = gufunc(a, signature=signature, extobj=extobj)
   1390         u = u.astype(result_t, copy=False)
   1391         s = s.astype(_realType(result_t), copy=False)

MemoryError:
```

I'm trying to process a dataset with a shape (91946, 171), all numerical, using the code below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
pd.set_option('display.max_columns',180)

dfk = pd.read_csv('data/kick.csv')dfk = pd.read_csv('data/kick.csv')

response =  dfk.state
features = dfk
features.drop('state', axis=1, inplace=True)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, response, 
                                                    random_state=321)

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

logreg = LogisticRegression()
logreg.fit(X_train,y_train)
ypred_lr = logreg.predict(X_test)

print("Accuracy on the test set: {0:.3f}".format(accuracy_score(ypred_lr, y_test)))


_, S, _ = np.linalg.svd(features) #fails here
print("Condition number from the SVD: {0:.1f}".format(np.max(S)/np.min(S)))
print("Condition number from cond:    {0:.1f}".format(np.linalg.cond(features)))
```